# Function if only accepts one input

Tags: python, function

My code is here: http://pastebin.com/bK9SR031 . I was doing the PygLatin exercise on Codecademy and got carried away, so most of it is... beginner.

Sorry that it's really long. The problem is that when the [Y/N] questions come up, no matter what I type in it behaves as if I input "yes".

One of the relevant excerpts:

```
def TryAgain():
    repeat = raw_input("\nStart over?[Y/N] ").lower()
    if repeat == "y" or "yes" :
        print "OK.\n"
        PygLatin()
    elif repeat == "n" or "no" :
        raw_input("\nPress ENTER to exit the English to Pig Latin Translator.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        TryAgain()
```

No matter what I input, it prints "OK." and then starts the PygLatin() function again.

Comment: `if` is not a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition in your first `if` statement:

```
 if repeat == "y" or "yes":
    print "OK.\n"
    PygLatin()
```

always evaluates to `True`, regardless of the value of `repeat`. This is because `"Yes"` is not an empty string (it's boolean value is `True`), so the `or` always results in `True`. One way to fix it is with:

```
if repeat == "y" or repeat == "yes":
    print "OK.\n"
    PygLatin()
```

another one (as sateesh mentions below) is:

```
if repeat in ("y","yes"):
    print "OK.\n"
    PygLatin()
```

You should also change the `else` condition accordingly

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Just to clarify, a string where `len(str) > 0` is equivalent to True in terms of the `if` statement?

Comment: For more on truth and false values, see [this reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) at the manual.

Answer (score 4):

Also it is better to do if check in below manner:

```
if repeat in ("y","yes"):
    ...
elif repeat in ("n","no"):
    ...
```

Comparing by keeping all possible values in a tuple (list) makes the code
readable. Also if there are more values to be compared with you can create 
a tuple (or list) to store those values and make comparison against the stored
values. Say something like below keeps code more readable:

```
acceptance_values = ('y','yes')
    ...
if repeat in acceptance_values :
    ...
```